# How to fixed position bottom right in html css

Tags: html, css

In this html code I want the height & width to remain 750x750 px. The Quote & Author is positioned in the center. However the source is positioned at the bottom right, If the quote is long the 'Source' text gets outside the image area. Could someone please help me know how can I fix the position to bottom right for the source, below is my HTML & CSS Code.

```css
.container
{
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: 750px;
    padding-bottom: 750px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;  /* coord system stop */
    top: 0px; /* IE? */
    background-size:cover;
    /* background-size:contain; */
background-position:center center;
}

.divWrapper
{
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     padding-top:50%; /* center the top of child elements vetically */
     padding-bottom:50%;
     height:0px;
     width: 750px;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
}

.tx
{               
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center; /* horizontal centering */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* child now centers itself relative to the  midline based on own contents */
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.5,  SizingMethod="auto expand")'; /*IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.5,  SizingMethod='auto expand'); /*IE6, IE7*/
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
    /* text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 8px 13px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 18px 23px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%); */
    font-size: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 75px 0 75px;
    font-family:'Righteous', cursive;
  

}

.markauthor {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: #ff000061;
}

.source{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200%;
    right: 0%;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #ffffff8a;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 8px 13px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 18px 23px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container" style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483721310020-03333e577078?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80');">    
<div class="divWrapper">        
<div style="font-size:30px; text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 8px 13px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 18px 23px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);" class="tx">Bodybuilding is much like any other sport. To be successful, you must dedicate yourself 100% to your training, diet and mental approach.  <br>  
<span style="font-size:18px; line-height:5;"><mark class="markauthor">—Arnold Schwarzenegger—</mark></span>  
<div class="source">advance.fitness.blog</div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you ask a question you can use the `<>` button to put your codepen directly into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the `.source` outside `tx` element and it will be easy:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 750px;
  padding-bottom: 750px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  /* coord system stop */
  top: 0px;
  /* IE? */
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-size:contain; */
  background-position: center center;
}

.divWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 50%;
  /* center the top of child elements vetically */
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  height: 0px;
  width: 750px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
}

.tx {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  /* horizontal centering */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* child now centers itself relative to the  midline based on own contents */
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.5,  SizingMethod="auto expand")';
  /*IE8 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.5, SizingMethod='auto expand');
  /*IE6, IE7*/
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 8px 13px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 18px 23px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%); */
  font-size: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 75px 0 75px;
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
}

.markauthor {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: #ff000061;
}

.source {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff8a;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 8px 13px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 18px 23px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container" style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483721310020-03333e577078?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80');">
  <div class="divWrapper">
    <div style="font-size:30px; text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 8px 13px rgb(0 0 0), 0px 18px 23px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);" class="tx">Bodybuilding is much like any other sport. To be successful, you must dedicate yourself 100% to your training, diet and mental approach. <br>
      <span style="font-size:18px; line-height:5;"><mark class="markauthor">—Arnold Schwarzenegger—</mark></span>
    </div>
      <div class="source">advance.fitness.blog</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @FaizSheikh welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: based on clarification...:

`divwrapper` is `absolutely positioned` in relation to its parent element which has `position:relative`.
Your source div has `top: 200%`. So, you have two simple choices here:

1. put the source div outside of div-wrapper - `make it a sibling` of div-wrapper and a child of the parent with `position:relative`, then, replace `top: 200%` with `bottom: 0`
2. add more bottom padding to div-wrapper so that the source div doesn't stick to the rest of the content (which is not very big and does not cover the entire area of the image). and just as above, change `top:200%` for `bottom: 0`

With #1, you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you mistakenly aligned the Author. I am referring to the 'source' which is at the bottom right outside of the image, the text reads "advance.fitness.blog", I want to get dis inside of the image in a bottom right fixed position

Comment: Thanks for the help Capagris

Comment: did this solve your issue? did the issue get solved some other way?